# Adding a hash-table to a hash-table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to add a hash-table to a hash-table using powershell. However, Im getting the following error:

`Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Dev'  Key being added: 'Dev'`

Here's my code:

```ps
$colors = @("black","white","yellow","blue")

$Applications=@{}

Foreach ($i in $colors)
{
    $Applications += @{
        Colour = $i
        Prod = 'SrvProd05'
        QA   = 'SrvQA02'
        Dev  = 'SrvDev12'
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, for one thing, all entries in a hash table need to have a Key and a Value. Using += like that I'm not even sure what the interpreter would do but you are definitely not giving it a key-value pair...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is something more like this:

```
$colors = @("black","white","yellow","blue")
$Applications=@{}
Foreach ($i in $colors)
{
    $Applications[$i] = @{
        Colour = $i
        Prod = 'SrvProd05'
        QA   = 'SrvQA02'
        Dev  = 'SrvDev12'
    }
}
```

I will also point out that Hashtables often need to be handled defensively. Each key must be unique but values do not need to be. Here is the typical method of handling that:

```
$colors = @("black","white","yellow","blue")
$Applications=@{}
Foreach ($i in $colors)
{
    if($Applications.ContainsKey($i)){
        #Do things here if there is already an entry for this key
    }else{
        $Applications[$i] = @{
            Colour = $i
            Prod = 'SrvProd05'
            QA   = 'SrvQA02'
            Dev  = 'SrvDev12'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. How would I add an object to the hashtable without adding a key. e.g. to build a hashtable that looks like this: `Applications=@(
@{
    Colour="blue";
    Prod="SrvProd05'"
    QA="SrvQA02";
    Dev="SrvDev12";
},
@{
    Colour="black";
    Prod="SrvProd05'"
    QA="SrvQA02";
    Dev="SrvDev12";
}.....
)`

Comment: You literally cannot add elements to a hashtable without a key. A hashtable without keys is called an array...

Comment: Ok so that would then be an array of hash tables?

Comment: Correct. So make $applications be an array not a hashtable. Also, depending on what your actual needs are, the canonical way to do something like this would be to use an array of custom objects.

Comment: Perfect - that clarifies things perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[EBGreen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50706209/45375) offers a solution for what you likely *meant* to do.

To complement that with an explanation of **why your code failed:**

- **When you use `+` to "add" two hashtables, their entries are *merged***: in other words: the entries of the RHS are added to the LHS hashtable.
  (Technically, a *new instance* is created with the merged entries.)
- However - by sensible design - **merging is only performed if the hashtables have *no keys in common***; otherwise, you'll get the error message you saw, complaining about duplicate keys.
  If this safeguard weren't in place, you would lose data if the values associated with duplicate entries differ.

Since your loop *repeatedly* tried to merge a hashtable with the same keys directly into an existing hashtable, your 2nd loop iteration invariably failed.

You can verify this more simply:

```
$Applications = @{}  # create empty hashtable.

# Merge a hashtable literal into $Applications.
# This works fine, because the two hashtables have no keys in common.
$Applications += @{ first = 1; second = 2 } 

# $Application now contains the following: @{ first = 1; second = 2 }

# If you now try to add a hashtable with the same set of keys again,
# the operation invariably fails due to duplicate keys.
$Applications += @{ first = 10; second = 20 } # FAILS

# By contrast, adding a hashtable with unique keys works fine:
$Applications += @{ third = 3; fourth = 4 } # OK

# $Application now contains: @{ first = 1; second = 2; third = 3; fourth = 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do some sort of "list of enum" and since I'm fairly new to PowerShell, the only thing I could think of is "HashTable of HashTables!".

Could not find a way to do it all "inline", and I got some "can't add a null key to a hashtable" error. After some experimentation I ended up with this, working exactly as I wanted :

```
$Enums = @{}
$Enums.Frequency = @{
    Daily = "daily"
    Weekly = "weekly"
    Monthly = "monthly"
}
$Enums.SomethinElse = @{
    Thing1 = "dflskdjf"
    Thing2 = 12
    Thing3 = $null
}
```

You can then use it simply

```
$Enums.SomethinElse.Thing2
```

or (if you add it to a Global Variable)

```
$Global:Enums.Frequency.Daily
```

It's not exactly the same as the example provided but directly in line with the topic, so I hope it helps someone ending up here :)